# Database for a server application

Tags: android, database

I want to start an android project for a module at university and I plan to make an online application that will communicate with a server. The app will have to record the user's log-in details and other information regarding their progress with the app on a database hosted on the server.

My idea is to set up a database on my raspberry pi which will act as a web server. The only problem is that I have limited experience with databases and I was wondering what will be the best one to use.

I have only used Oracle and it was very tedious to set it up, especially on Linux. From a lot of googling I reached the conclusion that MySQL will be the best choice. SQLite looks good too because it's easy to use, but I heard that it doesn't cope so well with concurrency.

**What do you guys think?**

*More info:*

> - The app will be a project for uni so it won't have huge amounts of data (but I plan to make it available on the store if I receive good feedback)
> - The database will have to work properly when data is requested simultaneously by multiple users
> - this will be a server application
> - can handle crashes

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about design decisions. Perhaps programmers.stackexchange.com would be a better forum. Or maybe dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to use MySQL. As you say SQLite it will not work for this propose.
Have you seen about Percona and MariaDB

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/02/25/percona-server-on-the-raspberry-pi-your-own-database-server-for-under-80/

Hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is the clear solution. Not only will it be better for performance, but more importantly it will give you the experience you need. More and More apps are linked to web based databases, and that choice is usually MySQL or SQL Server. The more familiar you are with MySQL the better prepared you will be for a future career AND there is all kinds of free help available on the Internet.

MySQL is free and a very functional databases, so the majority of small business use this database.